# Troubleshooting TaxJar (M2) Dependency Error

Tags: magento2, extensions, tax

I want to install TaxJar's M2 extension for Magento 2.3 but the readiness check fails due to a “Check Component Dependency” error. We can't suss it out. Before installing, I got confirmation via TaxJar's magento marketplace support portal:

**Jake at TaxJar · a day ago**
"*Yes, our extension is officially supported for Magento 2.3. We are in the process of updating our Marketplace listing to indicate 2.3 support.*"

I've reached back out to support but I'm in a hurry. Any tips on troubleshooting this?

Comment: Did you download the TaxJar M2 extension from Magento Marketplace? We're still waiting on Magento to finish the technical review and update our listing with 2.3 support. Currently v1.1.0 is available on the Marketplace, which does not have the updated composer.json file for Magento 2.3. Please go to our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-magento2-extension) and [download the latest version](https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-magento2-extension/archive/v1.2.0.zip). That should hopefully resolve the "Check Component Dependency" error.

Comment: Thank you, Jake! We'll give this a try and respond back with results.